# Laravel API Authentication with JWT

Tags: php, api, authentication, jwt

I'm reading the book: [Build APIs You Won't Hate](https://leanpub.com/build-apis-you-wont-hate), and it propose several Authentication methods:

1. Basic Auth
2. Digest Authentication
3. OAuth 1.0a
4. OAuth 2.0
5. OpenID
6. Hawk
7. Oz

I have a application that will have differents components

- Internal APIs
- Laravel WebApp with FB / Google Login via Socialite
- VueJs
- Mobile App

I will not have a public API.

I was thinking of using JWT to secure my APIs, but as I don't see it in the book, I'm wondering if I am not making a mistake.

Any advice will be apreciated!

Comment: I have answered this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376928/larvel-5-3-passport-jwt-authentication/41395074#41395074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JWT is a good practice for securing APIs it is not a mistake as far as I'm concerned.

But as Laravel 5.3 is now released and we have a Laravel Passport (OAuth2 Server) for API authentication which would be very help full to you I think.

You could refer the Laravel 5.3 release note for the document. Also Laracast has a free [video tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13) explained in detail.

Comment: What is the real benefit of using jwt instead of laravel internal api driver?

Comment: I ended using laravel pasaporte!

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved JWT auth on Laravel 5.2 using the jwt-auth Laravel package by Sean Tymon, https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

If you are interested in an example that uses vue.js for the UI, I have written a post to document my findings, http://jimfrenette.com/2016/11/laravel-vuejs2-jwt-auth/ and have posted the source code on github, https://github.com/jimfrenette/laravel-vuejs-jwt-auth